# Symbol for quaternion multiplication

Tags: notation, products, quaternions

I came accross different notations for the multiplication between two quaternions, e.g:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{q}_1 \circ \mathbf{q}_2 \quad \text{or} \quad \mathbf{q}_1 \otimes \mathbf{q}_2
\end{equation}

Which one should be preferred? Is there any standard notation for this operation ? The latter seems to be widely used for the outer product.

Comment: The other option is no symbol between the quaternions.

Comment: @J.G. well if this notation is considered as the standard notation for quaternion multiplication I'm ready to accept the answer

Comment: @ParclyTaxel for the first notation [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9524577) for example, for the second one I saw it on multiple websites when searching for an answer prior to post this question

Comment: Semanticscholar, bioRxiv, Montana State University.

Comment: [here](https://ece.montana.edu/seniordesign/archive/SP14/UnderwaterNavigation/Quaternions.html) and [here](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/733881v2.full), I cannot find the one on semanticscholar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbf q_1\circ\mathbf q_2$ recalls the interpretation of certain quaternions as rotations in 3D space, the *composition* of functions mapping said space to itself. $\mathbf q_1\otimes\mathbf q_2$ is a reminder that multiplication of quaternions is noncommutative.

But the most common and most concise notation is simply $\mathbf q_1\mathbf q_2$ – the quaternions being a skew-field where *multiplication is defined*, albeit a noncommutative one, is more than enough to merit using juxtaposition to denote multiplication. (This is also very common in group theory.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate the details on all notations